# Using SoftArtisan's WordWriter to merge Documents

Tags: c#, content-type

Here's my File Model:

```
    public class File
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string fileName { get; set; }
        public byte[] fileContent { get; set; }
        public string contentType { get; set; }
        public long fileSize { get; set; }
    }
```

with the content-type: application/msword

```
List<File> liste = new List<File>();
```

and my code trying to merge the documents that I read to a stream

```
    foreach (var doc in liste)
    {
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ms.Read(doc.fileContent, 0, Convert.ToInt32(doc.fileSize));
        Document documentToAppend = WA.Open(ms);
        baseDocument.Append(documentToAppend);
    }
    }
```

I get the following exception:

> This document is not a compatible Word document. WordWriter supports
>   documents created with Word 97, Word 2000, Word XP, and Word 2003. 
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read entire header; -1 bytes read;
>   expected 512 bytes

Any idea on how to set the content-type of the stream?
I have no means of writing the file to the disk and set it.

Comment: try to save document with .doc extension instead of .docx and then try

Comment: Document is kept in-stream so no extension is set. The stream is read from the byte[] of the Model.